# how to do function if one of two buttons clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different buttons that should call the same function, so I want to call the function if one of the two buttons is clicked, for example:

```
if(button1.isclicked() || button2.isclicked())

alert("clicked");
```

how to do this in jquery?

Comment: You make two different event listeners who both call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function buttonClicked() {
    alert("clicked");
}

button1.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
button2.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
```

Or, for IE8 (which doesn't have support for `addEventListener`:

```
button1.onclick = button2.onclick = buttonClicked;
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$button1.click(buttonClicked);
$button2.click(buttonClicked);
```